# Python - MatplotLib - Annotate Last Point

Tags: python, matplotlib

Wondering How to add
Marker + Corresponding value to the last point of a series.

To plot my series I use :

```
var= pd.read_excel("ExcelFilePath")
x = list(var['Date'])
y = list(var['Values'])
plt.plot(x,y,label='blabla')
```

Which Give (For example) :

[image]

How would I get this :

[image]

Comment: Use `plt.annotate` on the last value of x/y

Comment: @mozway I don't know how to do it dynamically. Can you show an example please ?

Comment: Sure, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71307105/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `annotate`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,6.5)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x,y,label='blabla')

plt.plot(x[-1], y[-1], marker='+')
plt.annotate(f'({x[-1]:.2f}, {y[-1]:.2f})', (x[-1], y[-1]), ha='right')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an image?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Plotly Library](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#line-charts-with-markers) for this.

e.g.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Oceania'")
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp', color='country', markers=True)
fig.show()
```

This will give you an output:
[image: plotly marker example]